# openCV H detection

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

For a drone contest, I need to do image processing with openCV to detect an “H” (for a helicopter landing pad). I have tried some classical algorithms, but the result is not satisfying.

- SIFT (and SURF): all the angles are the same (90 degrees) so even if it finds to “H”, it is mistaken about the orientation.
- matchTemplate: it is quite good, but it is not rotation and size invariant. So I need to make too many tests with different sizes and different orientations.
- Hough Line Transform: when the drone is too far from the target or too close to it, it doesn’t detect the same lines because of their thickness.
- Machine Learning for OCR: I ignore how to make it learn accurately because the template I am searching for is unique.

Can someone give me some advices please? :)

EDIT: Here is the "H" we need to detect: 
[image: H letter to be detected]

Comment: "it is mistaken about the orientation" - Does a helicopter H have an orientation that matters when it is simply being detected as a target to land on?

Comment: I am working with a quadricopter and I want to be able to land on with a correct orientation. And SURF doesn't always find the H because all angles are the same.

Comment: Don't think it matters so much how many blades it has. I imagine there could well not be a single technique which works ideally at all ranges - i.e. use different techniques at different ranges. For example if the H isn't visible/detectible then presumably the drone should fly a bounded search pattern.

Comment: So you don't think that there is a template matching algorithm that is size and orientation invariant?

Comment: I didn't say that, and I didn't not say it.

Comment: Can you post some sample images for the landing pad you're trying to detect?

Comment: @ardayigit How about making an H like [aruco marker](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) and using the build-in support in OpenCV 3 to get the orientation ?

Comment: @ardayigit what approach did you use?if possible can you provide the code for your drone?i'm trying to detect a H and land on it too but i can't find a way to detect a H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for recognising a helipad is to train a Haar classifier, and then run it on:

1. original image
2. Images rotated by plus and minus 22, 45, 68 ,90 degrees

A Haar classifier is trained by adding small rotations, so the above angles should be good enough to cover all rotations of the helipad in an image. another approach is to train multiple classifiers for different rotations; this is more common because Haar classifiers give up with the earliest evidence, and it is fast to run multiple classifiers than rotate a high resolution image.

One can also try template matching with rotations, but that will need a much larger number of rotations.

Comment: So it has a size and rotation invariant behaviour if I train it with enough images ?

Comment: Yes. A good example is the OpenCV's face detector, which can handle around 10 degrees of head rotations clockwise and counter-clockwise.

Comment: Don't you think that this algorithm takes much time for processing? I will use it on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Comment: Opencv face detecion can run on RPi Model 1b onwards; so this too should be fine (obviously, training has to be done on a desktop). But I am not sure about the frame rate. You can try running OpenCV's face detector on your platform and see if it works.